# Is "ward.D" a good agglomeration method in R?

Tags: r, python, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean

I need to do clustering on a large scale file (~12M rows, 18 features + id index). As a first step, i tried different algorythms in Python with a test sample (40k rows) which gave results (clearly defined clusters but the clusters are uneven in size). A coworker tried it in R and by my surprise had nearly the same clusters but way more even in distribution. Upon further documentation, i've seen that the "ward.D" (method used by my coworker in R) wasn't the "normal" ward that is available in Python. To reproduce the same clusters in python I had to take the square root of the distance, as per this snippet

```
d = np.sqrt(pdist(data_transform_scaled, metric='euclidean'))
```

Although the results are the same (pretty satisfying well defined clusters), I wonder if those are viable because in theory for the "ward.D" method in R you have to square the distance matrix (unlike "ward.D2" method) and if i do i have the same uneven clusters ("ward.D"+d^2 (in R) = "ward.D2"+d (in R) = ward+d (in Python) and "ward.D"+d (in R) = "ward.D2"+sqrt(d) (in R) = ward+sqrt(d) (in Python)). Is this method good or am I butchering the clustering ?